# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError issue only with buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-build-type

I am getting a very strange error like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.Fragments.SecondarySplashFragment` while running my application with `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'` in Android Studio (Windows version). This error completely seems to be very weird and new to me since I am facing this only with **Windows version** of Android studio, whereas it is working without any flaw in **Ubuntu version**. I really don't know what to do and completely stuck up with this error for the past two days. Any kind of solution would be much helpful for me. I am also posting my complete logcat below for your reference as follows.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.Fragments.SecondarySplashFragment$1
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.Fragments.SecondarySplashFragment.findViews(SecondarySplashFragment.java:71)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.Fragments.SecondarySplashFragment.onCreateView(SecondarySplashFragment.java:59)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5461)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-31 12:45:01.561 26135-26135/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

**Note:** This issue is happening only with `buildToolsVersion 23.0.1` but however if I change it to `buildToolsVersion 22.2.0` everything works fine without any issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a full clean and then rebuild.

Comment: Try with buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: @abforce I cleaned and rebuilt my project, but still issue continues.

Comment: @Chandru So, update your build tools to the latest version.

Comment: Post your code in SecondarySplashFragment.findViews